# SVG: Click underlying svg

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have this page with 2 svg images on it.
It seems the svg (item1) image is overlapping and preventing to click on the underlying svg (item2)

[image]

I tried using  pointer-events on the elements but i cant seems to get it working on the underlaying item2.

Maybe de svg is still blocking the 'click event'

This is the code:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="item1">
            <svg class="crossSvg">
                <line class="verticalLine" x1="50%" y1="0" x2="50%" y2="100%"></line>
                <line class="horizontalLine" x1="0" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%"></line>
                <rect class="itemSquare" x="50%" y="50%" width="10" height="10" transform="translate(-5,-5)"/>
                <text class="itemTitle" x="50%" y="50%" transform="translate(10,-10)">item1</text>
            </svg>
            <svg class="closeSvg">
                <rect class="closeSquare" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/>
                <line x1="90%" y1="50%" x2="91%" y2="51%"></line>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div id="item2">
            <svg class="crossSvg">
                <line class="verticalLine" x1="50%" y1="0" x2="50%" y2="100%"></line>
                <line class="horizontalLine" x1="0" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%"></line>
                <rect class="itemSquare" x="50%" y="50%" width="10" height="10" transform="translate(-5,-5)"/>
                <text class="itemTitle" x="50%" y="50%" transform="translate(10,-10)">item2</text>
            </svg>
            <svg class="closeSvg">
                <rect class="closeSquare" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/>
                <line x1="90%" y1="50%" x2="91%" y2="51%"></line>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.itemSquare').on('click', function(){
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#main{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

#item1, #item2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200vw;
    height: 200vh;
}
/* ---- positioning items ---- */
#item1{
    left: -90vw;
    top: -80vh;
    z-index:100;
}

#item2{
    left: -50vw;
    top: -70vh;
}
/* ---- item content ---- */
.itemContent{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 90vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
}

/* ---- SVG's ----- */
.crossSvg{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}

.verticalLine, .horizontalLine {
    stroke: black; 
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.itemSquare{
    display: hidden;
    fill: black;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    pointer-events: fill;
}

.closeSvg{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 95%;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.closeSquare{
    fill: black;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

I have put this in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fme21qx9/3/

Comment: You are 100% right and you cannot click the underlaying svg.

Comment: @skobaljic I know, but why not and how can i make it work...

Comment: You can't this way. You gotta bind click event to some parent element and than calculate from mouse position... or somehow reorder your SVGs using z-index on demand (like: select layers in Photoshop). Browser cannot know what SVG (layer) you wanted to click, since they are all one above the other - so it returns the top one.

Comment: @skobaljic I have read that its is possible to have to divs on top of each other, with background and have the underlaying one recieve the click event...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events   In addition to indicating that the element is not the target of mouse events, the value none instructs the mouse event to go "through" the element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead.

Comment: That is of no use for you. You can use z-index to reorder them, but element on top will always cover those underneath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable the pointer-events for both the wrapper element (`div#item1`) and the SVG (`svg.crossSvg`), since SVGs have a different pointer context.

If you add this to the end of your CSS, it works fine:

```
#item1 {
  pointer-events: none;
}
#item1 .crossSvg {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.itemSquare {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

*(Although styling with IDs in your selector isn't a best practise)*

**EDIT:**
Updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fme21qx9/4/) to reflect the changes in the answer and our discussion in the comments.

Comment: "Although styling with IDs in your selector isn't a best practise"
Why not? I thought when an element exists only once in the DOM, it was best to use an id instead of an class? Enlighten me!

Comment: It seems to work without disabling pointer-events on the crossSvg

Comment: @Nomistake yes, identifying a single occurring element in the DOM with an ID is good (so JS could find it quickly, for instance), but styling through an ID is not. The reason being that [CSS specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) is very high when using an SVG (you can now over-rule that rule only when including an ID in the selector).

Comment: Ok, i read the article, and will read it again :-) How would you apply the style?

Comment: Had a typo in my last comment (SVG -> ID*). And I'd need a bit more context for semantic classes, but (for example) you could just name them `.item`, you don't need to know the context of which item it is in the styles in this scenario. if you do, then you could name them `.item.foo` and `.item.bar`, where `foo` and `bar` are some other words that represent some use case for the items (if nothing else comes to mind, often times `.item.left` and `.item.right` will also work)

Comment: I updated your fiddle and added it to the answer (https://jsfiddle.net/fme21qx9/4/) - I used classes and HTML5 elements for styling instead of IDs. Let me know if you have any other questions! : )

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've really learned something. Although i had to read this site also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity to completly comprehend specificity